# Trying to optimize this MySQL query (select, insert and update in the same query)

Tags: php, mysql

i have this query from php:

```
mysql_query("INSERT INTO ".table_hack." (id,ip,count,lasttime) 
             VALUES (NULL,'".$ip."',1,NOW()) 
             ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE count=count+1, lasttime=NOW();");
```

---

As you can see im inserting a new record on the `table_hack` only if the *Unique* element is not present that in my case is *ip*. If the element is present the query updates de value of `count` in 1 and `lasttime` with the *NOW()* parameter.

I want also to know the value of count in the same query, it is possible?. I know that i could make another query but i will like to make it just in one (if is possible). Thanks for any help!

Comment: Any particular reason you want it to be 1 query?
Have you considered transactions?

Comment: Just curiosity and optimization.

Comment: The only optimalization I can think of is to check the affected_rows. If it returns 2 you know the count was updated so you can query for the count. If it returns 1 it only inserted the record so you know count=1 and don't have to do the select query.

Comment: What optimization? Got any particular problem?

Comment: Good to know this isn't possible but I'm surprised that everyone is curious why the OP would want one query. One query is faster and that matters at scale.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Nope, you can't.
Also, I see no reason for such a desire.

To me, it's interesting phenomenon. Such questions are quite often on Stackoverflow and I am curious why people so eager to combine queries into one call. 
And even more surprising fact that everyone are limiting themselves with just 2 queries, and nobody asks how to combine ALL the queries from the script into one mysql call.

Comment: Do these people shove a cake into the oven with the icing sugar - juswt incase the cake comes out iced?

Answer (score 0):

You can't combine an INSERT and SELECT query so you'll have to run two queries. Why would it be a problem to use two queries?

Answer (score -1):

You can not do it with standard php mysql functions. You can do it with Mysqli driver and method `multi_query()`, but it will be a 2 queries whatever.